# Sumif and delete cells in Mathematica

Tags: filtering

I want to create a simple "sumif" formula like in Excel. However, I am desperate since I cannot achieve a result.

First, I am importing an excel file with lot of datas.
data = Import[
"C:\Users\XXXX.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, "HeaderLines" -> 1]. The dimension is {1462, 99}.

I want to use "sumif"-formula like in excel and delete the redudant cells.
The data structure looks like this:
[image]

The result should give this:

[image]

Can you please help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Thomas, glad to have you here, one problem is that we (as a community in general) prefer to answer questions where the user has demonstrated what they have tried and where things are going wrongs as it decreases the chances that we are treated as a service to write code. Someone may come in with a complete answer later, but to get you started I'd look at the function `GroupBy` which can be used to easily aggregate by the first element then the other elements can be added with `Total` as well as the `Dataset` structure which (when used with the `Association` structure) makes a nice display

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a mac, and so I'm not sure how import will interact with your Windows-Excel data. This would be simpler if:

- you added a header for "Fruit" (first column)
- you put zeros in all of the empty cells
- you export to csv first

With those assumptions we can do this:

```
data = Import[pathToCsv, "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1];
data[GroupBy["Fruit"], Rest@*Total]
```

If you cannot make the above changes, then you'll probably need to munge the data once it's in Mathematica. Since you're on a different platform than what I'm using, I'm not confident I can predict what exact munging you'll need to do.

Comment: Or perhaps `Import[pathToCsv, "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1, "EmptyField" -> 0.];`

Comment: awesome! thanks!